# Getting the AUTO_INCREMENT value from php(not working)

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a simple mysqli code to select the current AUTO_INCREMENT value in a table named bookings.

After the code executes, nothing happens.I do not get any output in the screen.

Here is the code.

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = titan3d AND TABLE_NAME = bookings", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
    if (!mysqli_query($conn, "SET @a:='this will not work'")) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
    }
    myslqi_stmt_fetch_assoc($result);
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Is there something wrong with this code.Can somebody sort it out?

Comment: You never called `myslqi_stmt_fetch_assoc($result)` to get the row of results.

Comment: But there's only one row as it is the current value.

Comment: You still have to fetch it. `mysqli_query()` doesn't return the row, it returns a `mysqli_result` object.

Comment: You also have a syntax error in the query. You need to put quotes around the schema and table names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the query, you didn't quote the strings. And then you need to fetch the result row.

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'titan3d' AND TABLE_NAME = 'bookings'", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo "Auto-increment is {$row['AUTO_INCREMENT']}";
} else {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_fetch_assoc() in C:\xampp\htdocs\My Project\JSFiles\book.php:64 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\My Project\JSFiles\book.php on line 64

Comment: Sorry, got confused between prepared statements and regular queries. Should just be `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: OMG its working!!!!Thank you so much!!!That saved a hell of work for me!